# Traveling with expired visa in the E.U

Tags: air-travel

If you have an expired visa but an official N.I.E from the E.U., can you travel to another European country by plane without the visa needing to be renewed?

Comment: What's an N.I.E.?

Comment: And which European countries are you looking to travel between?

Comment: Do you mean you have an Número de Identificación de Extranjero, the Spanish tax identification number assigned to any foreigner? And, if so, what would that have to do with your ability to travel and not having a valid visa?